# Unable to generate venn diagram/plot in r

Tags: r

I'm currently doing a research project to identify some biomarkers. For that I tried to analyze the dataset GSE7670 as practice.I wanted to produce some visualizations for it.I tried the following code to analyze GSE_7670 dataset and get a visualization for it, but I encountered with the following error.

The code :

```
# Load necessary libraries
library(oligo)
library(limma)
library(VennDiagram)
library(GenomicRanges)

setwd("C:/Users/ANIRUDH.DESKTOP-74STHQ5/Downloads")

files <- list.files("GSE7670_RAW.tar", pattern = "\\.CEL.gz$", full.names = TRUE)

processed_data <- list()

for (file in files) {
  affyBatch <- read.celfiles(file)  
  rmaExpression <- rma(affyBatch)  
  processed_data[[basename(file)]] <- rmaExpression
}

design <- model.matrix(~factor(c("lung_cancer", "control")))

all_DE_genes <- c()

for (file_name in names(processed_data)) {
  rmaExpression <- processed_data[[file_name]]  
  fit <- lmFit(rmaExpression, design)   
  fit <- eBayes(fit)
  results <- decideTests(fit, method = "separate", adjust.method = "BH")
  DE_genes <- rownames(rmaExpression)[results$FDR <= 0.05] 
  all_DE_genes <- c(all_DE_genes, DE_genes)
}

# Create sets for Venn diagram
DE_genes_Sample1 <- all_DE_genes[grepl("Sample1", names(all_DE_genes))]
DE_genes_Sample2 <- all_DE_genes[grepl("Sample2", names(all_DE_genes))]

# Calculate Venn counts manually
venn_counts <- matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
venn_counts[1, 1] <- length(DE_genes_Sample1)
venn_counts[2, 2] <- length(DE_genes_Sample2)
venn_counts[1, 2] <- length(intersect(DE_genes_Sample1, DE_genes_Sample2))
venn_counts[2, 1] <- venn_counts[1, 2]

# Calculate areas for the Venn plot
area1 <- venn_counts[1, 1] - venn_counts[1, 2]
area2 <- venn_counts[2, 2] - venn_counts[1, 2]
cross_area <- venn_counts[1, 2]

# Create Venn plot
venn_plot <- draw.pairwise.venn(
  area1 = area1,
  area2 = area2,
  cross.area = cross_area,
  category = c("Sample1", "Sample2")
)

# Save the Venn plot as a PNG file
png("venn_diagram.png")
grid.draw(venn_plot)
dev.off()
```

The error : ```# Create Venn plot

> venn_plot <- draw.pairwise.venn(

- area1 = area1,
- area2 = area2,
- cross.area = cross_area,
- category = c("Sample1", .... [TRUNCATED]
  Error in if (max.x - min.x >= max.y - min.y) { :
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed```